# Powershell File Rename Date/Time

Tags: powershell

I have what should be a simple problem, but I just can't seem to get it right. I have a file that has two file extensions. We retrieve the file, decrypt it and save the encrypted file to a backup folder with a date/time stamp showing when the file was processed. All I want to do is to have the date/time stamp put before the two extensions instead of between them. There has to be a simple one line answer to this, but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Original File Name - DAILY AP FILES.ZIP.pgp

Current Rename File Name - DAILY_AP_FILES.ZIP-02182013-155123.pgp

Desired Rename File Name - DAILY_AP_FILES-02182013-155123.pgp

```
Get-ChildItem "$dlpath\*.pgp" | ForEach-Object {          
    Move-Item $_.FullName "$BackupFolder$($_.BaseName.Replace(" ", "_"))-$(Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy-HHmmss").pgp"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "$dlpath\*.pgp" | ForEach-Object {          
    Move-Item $_.FullName "$BackupFolder$($_.BaseName -replace " ", "_" -replace '\.([^\.]+)$')-$(Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy-HHmmss").pgp"
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I'd use `\..*?$` for replacing the second extension, though. Easier on the eye. ;)

Comment: true. I just wanted to ensure that it didn't remove parts of the name if it also included a `.` . After I became more active here on SO, I've realised that people use a lot of weird filenames :P

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! I knew there had to be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Get-ChildItem "$dlpath\*.pgp" | ForEach-Object {
$NewBaseName = ($_.BaseName.Replace(" ", "_")) -replace '^(.+\.).+','$1'           
Move-Item $_.FullName "$BackupFolder$NewBaseName-$(Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy-HHmmss").pgp"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification, improve because sort by date

```
$source_path="D:\Transferencia"
$backup_folder="D:\Transferencia_Backup"

Get-ChildItem "$source_path\*.pgp" | ForEach-Object {          
   Move-Item $_.FullName "$backup_folder\$($_.BaseName -replace " ", "_")-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyyMMdd_HHmmss").pgp"
}
```