# regarding a different post - Powershell File Rename Date/Time

Tags: powershell

[PowerShell File Rename Date/Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945253/powershell-file-rename-date-time/28867203#28867203) asked how to append the datetime stamp and I can see that it worked. However when I run this I end up prepending the file name with contents of `$BackupFolder`. I set `$BackupFolder = "C:\Data1"` and my files move to the C:\ with Data1 prepended to the name. I thought that `$BackupFolder` was the destination for the `Move-Item` cmdlet. What am I missing?

Comment: You need a backslash after the 1... `$BackupFolder = "C:\Data1\"`

Comment: Makes sense.  thanks.  I saw no reference to anyone else having a problem with that result so knew I was missing something.

Comment: This is why PowerShell has the Join-Path cmdlet.  In most cases, you shouldn't be concatenating directories as strings like the linked answer does.